# Offline mapping with custom image: How to center image and make it fill up the screen

Tags: cordova, dictionary, openlayers, offline

I want to make an application where you can pan and zoom an image fullscreen. Markers would reveal information about that part of the image. This is much like a map.
So I started playing around with Phonegap and OpenLayers offline mapping. Now I succesfully achieved this, but I don't seem to grab the coordinate system.
When I run my app on Android it shows a blank screen until I touch the zoom control. Then all of a sudden the image is visible and you can drag it around and explore it.
I assume it's got something to do with the coordinate system.

Here's my init function that basically has everything to show the map and make it work:
I'm looking for a way to center my image and make it fill up the entire screen when running this app.

```
var init = function () {
// create map
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    theme: null,

    // komt van http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(  0.0, -3433.0, 3433.0, 0.0 ),
    maxResolution: 16.000000,
    numZoomLevels: 7,
    // end

    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation({
            dragPanOptions: {
                enableKinetic: true
            }
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom()
    ],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "TMS Layer","",
                {  url: '', serviceVersion: '.', layername: '.', alpha: false,
                    type: 'jpg', getURL: overlay_getTileURL,
                    transitionEffect: 'resize'
                })
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(1000, 1000),
    zoom: 3
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very common problem - you need `map.zoomToMaxExtent();` in the end of your init function.

Comment: This indeed takes care of showing the entire map. It also creates empty space aroun it to fill the screen. Therefore I added map.zoomTo(2) to make sure it filled up the screen.